# Limiting VPC subnet access for NAT OpenVPN clients

Tags: openvpn, aws

I'm currently testing OpenVPN to give developers limited access to AWS VPC's.

Assuming I have 3 VPC's... VPC-A, VPC-B, VPC-C, each of these with private and public subnets.

The OpenVPN server will be in the public subnet VPC-A-Pub-1.

VPC-A is peered to the other 2 VPC's.

I want developers to have direct access to VPC-A, and VPC-B, but not VPC-C.

My openvpn server.conf

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key

dh dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "route 10.130.0.0 255.255.192.0" # VPC-A
push "route 10.131.0.0 255.255.192.0" # VPC-B

keepalive 10 120
auth SHA384
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn-status.log

log         /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 3
mute 20

plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so /etc/openvpn/auth/auth-ldap.conf
client-cert-not-required
```

Just regarding the routes, 10.130.0.0, and 10.131.0.0 are for VPC-A and VPC-B.

Additionally, in the rc.local, I'm setting up nat like so...

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o ens5 -j MASQUERADE
```

With this setup, I can now connect to resources in VPC-A, and VPC-B, but not VPC-C. However I'm just wondering if this is actually a safe way to do it. The routes are pushed to the client, but does that mean that the user could simply add an additional route at their end for 10.132.0.0, to give themselves access to VPC-C?

Is there a proper, secure way to ensure that VPN clients can never get to a particular VPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing problem sounds like something you could quickly prove by simply trying it out, although I imagine it will work. The routes pushed to the client are really just suggestions, and don't stop the user from adding other routes. If your server knows how to route the packets and there is nothing else preventing it from doing so, people can likely access VPC-C.

Assuming you have a valid case for the server to be peered with VPC-C at all, the correct solution would be to implement firewall rules on the server that prevent access to the VPC-C subnet from the VPN interface.